# On the equivalence of two traces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

If we are given 
$$\rm{Trace}\{ G \: a \: a^T\} = \rm{Trace}\{H \: w \: w^T\}$$
where $a$ is $N \times 1$ vector, $G$ is $N \times N$ symmetrical matrix, and $w^T = [a^T \: t^T \: 1]$ and $t$ is another $N \times 1$ vector, how can I find $H$ in terms of $G, a, t$?

Comment: I doubt $H$ is not uniquely determined. Maybe there is a natural choice from these data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  For given $a$ and $t$, $\phi: H \to \text{Trace}(H w w^T)$ is a linear functional on the space of $(2N+1) \times (2N+1)$  matrices.  The matrices $H$ for which $\phi(H)$ takes a given value $\text{Trace}(G a a^T)$ form a hyperplane in this space.  You have given us no reason to favour any one member of this hyperplane over the others.

Comment: The only other information I know is that $W = w w^T$ is positive semidefinite of rank 1. How can I pick up any of those members? I need any $H$ that make the LHS equals the RHS. Thanks.

Comment: $w w^T$ is always positive semidefinite, and has rank $1$ whenever $w$ is not $0$.  You might try $H = \text{Trace}(G a a^T) w w^T/(w^T w)^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would appreciate if you refer to a specific section in a textbook to understand how you get it. I do not want the final answer.

Comment: It all follows from linearity of Trace, associativity of matrix multiplication, and $\text{Trace}(AB) = \text{Trace}(BA)$ whenever $AB$ and $BA$ both make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.